# How to put the value of an input in URL using JSP pages with Spring

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input

```
<input id="quantity-input" type="number" min="1" value="1">
```

And I want to put the value of that input at the end of the href when it is clicked

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/products/add/'">Add</button>
```

Maybe it's simple html/js but i can't find how to do it and if I have a way to make it with JSTL or something

Comment: you need do it using js ?

Comment: I can do it as I want

Comment: You should use JS, JSP is processed in the server side.

Comment: Ok, but i'm pretty bad with js, do you know a way to detect changes on that input ? I have already tried with "onchange" but i had some problems for example when i hit the button directly after having changed the value of the input, it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function (e.g. `fun()` in the example given below) on the click of the button. Inside the function, you can get the value of the input field and append the same at the end of the existing string (i.e. `/products/add/`).

Do it as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <script>
            function fun() {
                var url = "/products/add/"+document.getElementById("quantity-input").value;
                window.location.href = url
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="quantity-input" type="number" min="1" value="1">
        <button onclick="fun();">Add</button>
    </body>
</html>
```